Container messed up widget
So I am making a widget in flutter that contains some text and since I add the "Subscribe" button it appears that pixels are messing up .. I don't know if I should wrap the container in a column and what I should add to stop messing the Ui, or should I wrap it in a stack? add expanded ? or make the subscribe button smaller? but I like it this size
Stack(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                    spreadRadius: 5,
                                    blurRadius: 7,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                  )
                                ]),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.2,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.1,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0),
                                    child: CircleAvatar(
                                      radius: 50,
                                      backgroundImage: ((snaps.data?.data()
                                                  as Map)['avatarUrl'] ==
                                              'default')
                                          ? const NetworkImage(
                                              "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png"

                                              //  activity.imageUrl,

                                              )
                                          : NetworkImage((snaps.data?.data()
                                              as Map)['avatarUrl']),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    height: 170.0,
                                    // width: double.infinity,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.5,
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            width: 120.0,
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                (snaps.data?.data()
                                                    as Map)['name'],
                                                // activity.name,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                ),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                maxLines: 2,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.5,
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            width: 120.0,
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                (snaps.data?.data()
                                                    as Map)['address'],
                                                // activity.name,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                ),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                maxLines: 2,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          (snapshot2.data?.data()
                                              as Map)['category'],
                                          // activity.type,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 20,
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                            height: 80,
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.78,
                                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                              shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                                              color: Colors.grey[200],
                                              shadows: [
                                                BoxShadow(
                                                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                                  blurRadius: 10,
                                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            child: const Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceEvenly,
                                                children: [
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .center,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Subscribers',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .bold),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text('356',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .grey)),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  VerticalDivider(
                                                    indent: 8,
                                                    endIndent: 8,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .center,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Programs',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .bold),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text('8',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .grey)),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  VerticalDivider(
                                                    indent: 8,
                                                    endIndent: 8,
                                                  ),
                                                  Expanded(
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .center,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          'Ratings',
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontWeight:
                                                                  FontWeight
                                                                      .bold),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text('5.0',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold,
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .grey)),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ])),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 30,
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width /
                                                2.5,
                                            child: ElevatedButton(
                                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                        vertical: 16),
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(32),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              onPressed: () {},
                                              child: Text(
                                                "SUBSCRIBE",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          right: 35,
                          child: TextButton(
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                              disabledBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            onPressed: null,
                            child: Text(
                              'TOP 5',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),


Remove container's height that is height: 80 or increase height.

I removed it , it still show overflowed , I increased it , same

It's the button SUBSCRIBE That messed what is up

or the sizedbox on top subscribe button
